# How to 'dynamically' compile regular expressions as (not) binary?

Tags: python, regex

I started to rework my python framework to be python3-compatible. One issue I ran into: type errors for my regex matches. Turns out, that *some* of my regexes need to be compiled as binary to avoid type errors when matching against the bytes that some other function produce.

So I thought to write something like this

```
@classmethod
def contains(cls, pattern, value):
    """
    :param pattern: A regular expression pattern. If input is plain string, will be compiled on the fly
    :param value: A string that might contain the given pattern (can be multi line string)
    :returns: True if pattern is found in value
    """
    compiled_pattern = pattern
    if type(pattern) is str:
        if type(value) is bytes:
            print("binary pattern")
            compiled_pattern = re.compile(b'{}'.format(pattern))
        else:
            print("normal pattern")
            compiled_pattern = re.compile(pattern)        

    if compiled_pattern.search(value) is None:
        return False
    return True
```

Creating the "normal" patterns works nicely, but for "binary" ones, I get

```
compiled_pattern = re.compile(b'{}'.format(pattern))
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'format'
```

(this error is for python3; python2 directly throws a syntax error at me)

So, how do I instruct python to compile a regex from a variable, but as binary?

( I know that there are other ways to solve the underlying problem; for example by doing a value = str(value) in that very method )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is that `b'{}'` gives you a different result in python2 and python3:

python2.7:

```
type(b'{}') # <type 'str'>
```

python3:

```
type(b'{}') # <class 'bytes'>
```

What's actually happening, is it's doing this:

```
(b'{}').format(pattern)
```

and so it works in 2.7, since format is a method of `str`.

You need to use [`bytes(pattern, encoding)`](http://www.pythoncentral.io/encoding-and-decoding-strings-in-python-3-x/)

Answer (score 2):

```
re.compile(bytes(pattern, 'utf-8'))
```

Make sure you use the same encoding as the "other function".

You can use the above method to convert to bytes, but I'd recommend you convert the value provided by the other function to unicode instead.

Answer (score 2):

And just for completeness: the one other solution is to not change the type of the regular expression - but of the incoming data, for example like:

```
if value is bytes:
    value = str(value)
```